# Fuzzy number confusion in Data envelopment analysis R.

Tags: data-analysis, programming, fuzzy-logic

I was learning data envelopment analysis and I was confused when I started dealing with fuzzy data. How can I know if a variable in my dataset is a fuzzy number or not? They mentioned that with figures but I don't know how they got those figures. Here is the screenshots of those pictures.
[image]

And even if I know that, how can I figure out what is `Inputs.mL`, `Inputs.mR`, `Inputs.dL`, `Inputs.dR`, `Outputs.mL`, `Outputs.mR`, `Outputs.dL`, `Outputs.dR` (Those terms are from the function `read_data_fuzzy()` from the library `deaR`).